# Why is it called "carbonation"?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, aqueous-solution, nomenclature

Why is it referred to as "carbonation" and we drink "carbonated" beverages when carbonate is $\ce{CO3}$ while $\ce{CO2}$ (carbonite?) is present in carbonation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. Carbonate is $\ce{CO}_3^\color{red}{2-}$ (an ion), not $\ce{CO3}$. Carbonite is $\ce{CO}_2^\color{red}{2-}$.

Carbonation involves dissolving $\ce{CO2}$ gas in water. It turns out that $\ce{CO2}$ reacts (maybe not the best term to use here*) with water via the following reaction $$\ce{CO2 + H2O -> CO3^{2-} + 2H+}$$

So you have effectively *carbonated* the soft drink.

When you depressurize the bottle by opening it, the reverse reaction occurs and you get carbon dioxide.

<sup>*Such dissociation is normal and integral to dissolution of polar solutes in water, so generally it is considered as *part* of the dissolution</sup>

Comment: I've always wondered about carbonite. Has anyone ever produced salts of it? Can you be frozen in it?

Comment: @BenNorris: Apparently it's a hypothetical radical, used to explain certain phenomena. [Its conjugate acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihydroxymethylidene) exists in the gas phase, but not yet known to exist as a solution.  Go figure :S

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64416/does-the-carbon-dioxide-dianion-exist