# Does the carbon dioxide dianion exist?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, photochemistry

I have heard that the dianion of carbon dioxide, $\ce{CO2^{2-}}$ was named carbonite.

Does such a species really exist? Basically, is it stable enough to be a plausible molecule? If so, under what conditions is this true?

This question is very confusing to me, I understand the concept somewhat but I don't know what information I need in order to figure out the answer.

Comment: Hard to judge questioner/reader chemistry introduction level, hard to judge likeliness of possible confusion with $\ce{CO_3^{2-}}$ carbonate.

Answer (score 10):

The obvious *Star Wars* puns aside, I have never heard about the dianion of a carbon dioxide **dianion** and/or that it was named carbonite.

However, the carbon dioxide radical anion, $\ce{CO2^{.-}}$, is experimentally available.

Typically, it is generated by hydrogen atom abstraction from formate, $\ce{HCOO-}$, using $\ce{HO^.}$ radicals. The $\ce{HO^.}$ radicals, in turn, are obtained from vacuum ultraviolet (VUV) irradiation of water at a wavelength of $\lambda = 175~\mathrm{nm}$.

---

**UPDATE**

Apparently, I was **wrong** about the dianion! As *Mithoron* pointed out in his comment, species like $\ce{(M^+)_2CO2^{2-}}$, formed in the reaction carbon dioxide with alkali metals in argon or nitrogen matrixes, have been detected by IR spectroscopy. See [*Inorganic Chemistry*, **1984**, *23*, 177-184](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ic00170a013) for details.

Comment: It looks dianion also was made https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231343327_Carbon_dioxide_activation_by_alkali_metals_2_Infrared_spectra_of_MCO2-_and_M22CO22-_in_argon_and_nitrogen_matrixes

Comment: $\ce{CO2^{\bullet -}}$ is also thought to be a key intermediate in the electrochemical reduction of carbon dioxide. (e.g., [PDF link](http://www.lemp7.cnrs.fr/productions/Prod_LEM_pdf/422_J_Chem_Soc_Faraday_Trans.pdf))

Comment: @hBy2Py Brian, that's interesting :) Actually, I think that I cited one of the authors, Jean-Michel Saveant, more than once. I always went the other way: oxidation of carboxylates to the corresponding radicals, followed by decarboxylation.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Mithoron, but that is just preposterously cool.

Comment: Carbonite di-anion may exist not only in low temperature matrices.  [Wikipedia reports](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihydroxymethylidene) that it may be a surface species when carbon monoxide is adsorbed onto some oxide surfaces including line and magnesia.

Comment: Quick note:  In your edit you wrote that the counterion of the carbonite di-aniin salt was $\ce{M_2^{2+}}$, but when I asked about the existence of such cations I got comments that this was wrong.  The abstract apparently had been poorly written and was misread.  Properly there are two separate monatomic alkali metal cations per carbonite ion, and I corrected the nomenclature.