# Oxyanionic Series and Chemical names

Tags: nomenclature

If there is only 1 Oxyanion in a series, what is it’s prefix/suffix? Also, if I have Copper(I) Iodate, how do I know how many oxygen atoms are in the compound?

Comment: Also, does a specific amount of oxygen correspond to the prefix/suffix? Example: compound with 1 oxygen= Hypo-X-ite, 2 oxygens= X-ite, 3 oxygens= X-are, and 4 oxygens = Per-X-ate

Comment: Like this matters, really. On one hand people want some complicated IUPAC names, on the other still use naming from what XIX century?

Comment: I agree, but this is also for homework XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If there is only 1 oxyanion in a series, what is it’s prefix/suffix?

This anion gets the "-ate" suffix and no prefix. Example: Carbonate $\ce{CO3^2-}$. There is no "carbonite" to freeze Han Solo in; the $\ce{CO2^2-}$ anion does not exist. Carbon does form other oxyanions, like oxalate, $\ce{C2O4^2-}$, but these anions also vary in the number of carbon atoms.

> Also, if I have Copper(I) Iodate, how do I know how many oxygen atoms are in the compound?

Iodine can form multiple oxyanions, although hypoiodite and iodite are not particularly stable:

- $\ce{IO-}$ - hypoiodite
- $\ce{IO2^-}$ - iodite
- $\ce{IO3^-}$ - iodate
- $\ce{IO4^-}$ - metaperiodate
- $\ce{IO6^5-}$ - orthoperiodate

With the exception of the "meta" and "ortho" periodates, this same trend is seen for two other halogens, chlorine and bromine (chlorine shown):

- $\ce{ClO-}$ - hypochlorite
- $\ce{ClO2^-}$ - chlorite
- $\ce{ClO3^-}$ - chlorate
- $\ce{ClO4^-}$ - perchlorate

Comment: Thank you, but let’s say I didn’t know Iodine could form multiple oxyanions, how would I know how many oxygen atoms are in Iodate?

Comment: And vice versa. If I have BaIO4, how do I know it’s name if I don’t have the other oxyanions with iodine?

Comment: @Jondue - You have two choices: Look it up or memorize it.

Comment: Actually carbonite was detected! https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64416/does-the-carbon-dioxide-dianion-exist

Comment: Or, as a surface species: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02069193